# Retrofit: How to get the name of the called service method?

Tags: java, android, retrofit, retrofit2

I have an `Interceptor` implementation that adds a required header to a request. From time to time developers forget to add the required `@Header("foobar")` annotation to the service interface method. In this case my `Interceptor` throws an `IllegalArgumentException` indicating the missing annotation. Unfortunatly it is not clear in the exception message which service method was called. 
I want to provide the name of service method that was called. It it possible?

Here is my (kotlin) code:

```
    @Throws(IOException::class)
    override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {

        val request = chain.request()
        val identifier = request.header(REQUIRED_HEADER) ?: run {
                  val methodName= // how to get the service method name?
                  throw IllegalArgumentException("Missing annotation >@Header(REQUIRED_HEADER)< on service method: $methodName ")

        }
```

Retrofit it self can add the method name in case a paramter is not annotated with a retrofit annotation.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No Retrofit annotation found. (parameter #1)
    for method HonkAndFlashFalService.startHonkAndFlash
    at retrofit2.ServiceMethod$Builder.methodError(ServiceMethod.java:755)
    at retrofit2.ServiceMethod$Builder.methodError(ServiceMethod.java:746)
    at retrofit2.ServiceMethod$Builder.parameterError(ServiceMethod.java:764)
```

Comment: add code snippet as well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a bit of digging I discovered that retrofit2 injects an invocation object into the original request which should be accessible via:

```
chain.call().request().tag(retrofit2.Invocation.class))
```

The tag is being injected in retrofit2 in the RequestFactory.create(Object[] args) method.

Note, this was done with retrofit2 2.5.0, earlier versions may differ

Comment: Which version of retrofit / okhttp do you use? On my side `chain.call().request()` returns an `okhttp3.Request` where the `tag()` method has no args. Also the type `retrofit2.Invocation` is not present.

Comment: The API you mention seems to be available in okhttp `3.14.0` and above.